# Access 2010 VBA: If no records match filter, display "No records found"

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'd like a query to return text such as "No records found matching criteria." or the like when there are no records that meet the entered criteria.

I'm using Access 2010 and can use VBA or SQL. I'd imagine the query (SQL) is where this would be most easily applied.

Comment: Posting some code would be great.

Comment: No. Test the number of records returned on the client side and substitute your message at that point. Don't make SQL responsible for UI features.

Comment: @Joe, is this because the SQL is less efficient at it or is it simply "best practices"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first thought would be to do something like this::

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE SomeID = 123" 
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)
If rst.recordcount = 0 Then
    Debug.print "Nothing to see, move along"
Else
    ' Do something useful
End If
```

If you are using a query built in the QBE you can do something similar and open the recordset using the stored querydef instead of a sql string.